# Deleting ALL cells that contain a certain string, and shifting to the left

Tags: replace, google-sheets

I have a customer database file where the data has been input incorrectly and the column names do not match up with the data.

I am using Google Sheets.

To fix this, I need to select all the cells that contain a time stamp, one example of such is:

```
2016-06-21 08:42:09 UTC
```

I would like to not only select these cells, but delete their contents, and shift the cells to the left.

This would fix my problem! However, I have no idea if this is possible?

NOTE: These time stamps do not always appear in the same row, and sometimes appear more than once per row.

Here is a visual representation of my problem:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/uNbUfy7]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and do:

```
\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ .*
```

[image: 0]